# Encrypt XML File

Tags: php, xml, encryption, guid

I have a XML file like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>1
<!-- Time-stamp: "bibliography.xml   3 Mar 2008 16:24:04" -->2
<!DOCTYPE bibliography SYSTEM "bibliography.dtd" >3
<bibliography>4
  <book key="Michard01" lang="fr">5
    <title>XML langage et applications</title>
    <author>Alain Michard</author>
    <year>2001</year>
    <publisher>Eyrolles</publisher>
    <isbn>2-212-09206-7</isbn>
    <url>http://www.editions-eyrolles/livres/michard/</url>
  </book>
  <book key="Zeldman03" lang="en">
    <title>Designing with web standards</title>
    <author>Jeffrey Zeldman</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <publisher>New Riders</publisher>
    <isbn>0-7357-1201-8</isbn>
  </book>
  ...
</bibliography>6
```

I would like to encrypt the XML file to look like a string of 32 characters

like that :

```
6DA5F750-9CB7-3E81-74AD-21B3747BAC8T
```

Comment: Don't you mean you want to hash te file?

Comment: All that information, in 32-characters?

Comment: How can you predefine that you need the encrypted version in exact 32 characters without knowing the length of input string if it is variable?

Comment: Where do these numbers at the end of lines come from? 1,2,3,4 or 6 or example? - ah here: http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~carton/Enseignement/XML/Cours/Syntax/index.html - those are footnotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "like that":

```
6DA5F750-9CB7-3E81-74AD-21B3747BAC8T
```

Looks pretty much like a [GUID - a Globally unique identifier<sup>*­Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

It's not encryption, but representing. So the GUID stands for the XML document.

There are many ways to generate these GUIDs, all these have their pros and cons so you need to decide on what works best for you in your case. On SO we have some QA material about all this (for example a listing related to [PHP with XML and GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+xml+guid)), so just do some research until you've come up with what you've need. Let me know if you've got any more questions or problems doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to encrypt a document of that size into 32 characters.

You can hash (`md5()` gives 32 characters, `sha1()` 40), but that's one-way, whereas encryption requires being able to undo it.

Comment: md5 actually gives 16 characters, not 32.

Comment: @hakre 32 hexadecimal characters. 128-bits.

Comment: @hakre Uh, no. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 "An MD5 hash is typically expressed as a hexadecimal number, 32 digits long."

Comment: yes 128 bits, 16 octets or characters and can be written 32 hex-digits, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Also both functions in PHP allow the raw output. So they can give 16 characters and 20 characters with no problems.

Comment: They can, but it's hardly the default behaviour, so posting your initial comment as a correction saying "not 32" remains inaccurate.

Comment: well let's say a string of 16 hexadecimal numbers with two digits each resulting in a PHP string length of 32. ^^